How do initial conditions of ODEs relate to initial/boundary conditions of solving PDEs?
Consider the ODE with initial condition
\begin{align}
y'=f(x,y),\quad y(x_0)=y_0.
\end{align}
Suppose it's solution can be written in the form
\begin{align}
u(x,y)=C,
\end{align}
then $u$ must satisfy
\begin{align}
u_x+f(x,y)u_y=0.
\end{align}
My question, then, is how do we translate the initial condition from the ODE into a boundary/initial condition for the PDE? If I have a simple ODE which can be solved, I simply evaluate $u(x_0,y_0)$ to find $C$. But, if I am to restrict myself to the more general case where I cannot find the solution to the ODE I'm not sure how to translate it to a condition I would expect from a PDE.
Perhaps the method of characteristics may shine some light on this? I can imagine the translation the other way, PDE BC/IC to ODE IC, is a sort of non-injective process and we can't go the other way?

Any PDE of that form that can be solved without the method of characteristics will almost certainly be simple enough that the original ODE can be solved. I don't think moving from an ODE to a PDE helps much in general

@whpowell96 Thanks for the comment. I have not seen a method that works when method of characteristics fails as well. But that doesn't mean that a method will never exist, I am still interested in my question.
